# Unique list with two criteria, advanced filter

Tags: excel, filter, unique

I want to create a unique list that extracts a six digit number that begins with seven.  Currently I am using a formula like, `=IF(AND(LEFT(A2,1)="7",LEN(A2)<>6),0,A2)` but, there are over 500 numbers.

Is there a way to use the Advanced filter to accept both criteria for each cell and also create a unique list of integers?  This is for a colleague who tries to stay away from VBA.

For example,

```
242950  (assume this is in cell A2 and every following number is down a row)  
240338      
240427      
240419     
240435      
713082      
713104            
7131472     
2386274      
238104    
7124932  
712655  
712701  (A15)
```

My desired result would create the list

```
713082   
713104    
712655   
712701
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up your criteria as such:

- C1 is blank
- C2 put the formula: `=AND(--LEFT(A2,1)=7,LEN(A2)=6)`

Then set up your Advanced filter:

- List Range: `$A$1:$A$15`
- Criteria Range: `$C$1:$C$2`
- Check Unique records only

[image]

Hit OK.

[image]

Comment: really cool answer and clicking unique records works here.  Could you explain the `--`?  I've seen it in `SUMPRODUCT` equations but, does it serve a similar purpose here?

Comment: The `--` turns a text that looks like a number to a number.  It basically multiplies the return of the Left which is a string by `-1 * -1`.  This forces Excel to recognize it as a number. @SozDaneron  I could not decide if you wanted a unique or not as your desired output has duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are approaching the issue the wrong way. As you stated these are just numbers, so  instead just retrieve all values greater and equal to 70,000 and less than 80,000 (or between).

You can do this using a standard filter and selecting the between option.

Or if you want to use an advanced filter you would create 2 options in the criteria range specified as:

```
>=70000
<80000
```

Comment: This was a decent idea but, some of the numbers repeat.